how to implement render in view controller after get request Django
I have the following template in which I added a get request
function openProject(projectId) {
        fetch(`/segmentation/test/`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            mode: 'same-origin',
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log("Всё супер");
            } else {
                console.error('Ошибка при открытии проекта');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Произошла ошибка:', error);
        });
    }

and the next view
in it I collect all the information about images and tags that relate to this project
def test(request):
    projectId = request.GET.get('projectId')
    if projectId:
        project = Project.objects.get(pk=projectId)
        _tags = project.tags.all()
        _images = project.images.all()
        print(_images)
        polygons = []
        colorPol = []
        for i in range(len(_images)):
            polygons.append([])
            colorPol.append([])

        for i in range(len(_images)):
            for rect in Rect.objects.all().filter(inImage=i+1):
                tempArr = []
                colorPol[i].append(rect.tag.Name)
                for p in rect.points.all():
                    tempArr.append([p.x, p.y])
                polygons[i].append(tempArr)
    else:
        _tags = []
        _images = []
        polygons = []
        colorPol = []

    return render(request,
                  'segmentation/testDraw.html',
                  {'tags': _tags, 'images': _images, 'title': 'Test Draw', 'rectForImage': polygons,
                   'colorPolArr': colorPol})

My urls:
app_name = 'segmentation'

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', test, name='testDraw'),
    path('projects/', project_show, name='project_show'),
]

please help me solve this problem
I tried changing the request to post, but as far as I understand it doesn’t matter

What errors did you encounter?
